# Mocking Do-Not-Cares in IHttpControllerActivator

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, moq

I'm in the middle of refactoring my test harness (SpecFlow 2.0.0 over NUnit 3.0.5797.27534) to drive my controllers for a particular test.

```
Scenario: FluxCapacitor Works
   Given I have entered '11-05-1955' into the Time Circuits
   When I get the DeLorean up to 88 mph
   Then the date on the newspaper should be '11-05-1955'
```

It's a common scaffolding exemplar that I run for my test architecture.

```
public class TimeController: ApiController
{
    private TimeProvider TimeProvider{get;set;}
    public TimeController(TimeProvider timeProvider)
    {
       this.TimeProvider = timeProvider;
    }
}
[HttpGet]
[Route("Time;now")]
public DateTime GetCurrentTime()
{
   return TimeProvider.Current.Now; 
}
```

...so, I'm trying to mock out the `Then` call to do...

```
[Then(@"the date on the newspaper should be '(.*)'")]
public void ThenTheDateOnTheNewspaperShouldBe(string p0)
{
   DateTime expected = DateTime.Parse(p0); 
   Startup startup = new Startup();

   Hosting.MySystemStartupOptions options = new Hosting.MySystemStartupOptions();


   //+===================================================================+
   //[KAB] This is the line that I think is of primary importance in this
   options.Dispatcher = DelegateThatReturnsMyMockControllerActivator();
   //+===================================================================+
   startup.Register = () => { return options;};

   //+===================================================================+
   //[options.Dispatcher] gets pushed down to my WebApiConfiguration that
   //executes [Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),options.Dispatcher]
   //+===================================================================+
   using(WebApp.Start(url: "http://localhost:9000/", startup:startup.Configuration))
   using(var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
   using(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(ResourceUnderTest.ToString()).Result)
   {
      if(response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
         Assert.Fail("you suck");
      }

      //never getting past, because I suck.
   }
}
```

so the delegate that returns my `IHttpControllerActivator` is actually called `Composer`

Composer returns a mock.

`Composer` looks thusly:

```
Composer = () =>
{
   var request = new Moq.Mock<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage>();
   var descriptor = new Moq.Mock<System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor>();
   var dispatcher = new Moq.Mock<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator>();

   Type controllerType = typeof(resources.controllers.TimeController);

   var provider = new Moq.Mock<TimeProvider>();
   provider.Setup(time => time.Now).Returns(Variable); //<=Variable is initialized in the `Given`

   TimeProvider timeProvider = provider.Object;
   Service = new resources.controllers.TimeController(timeProvider: timeProvider);


   //+======================================================================+
   //I can't figure out if there is a way to have "all calls to Create for a
   //specific controllerType, but I do not care about the request or the 
   //descriptor" returns [Service]
   dispatcher.Setup(context => context.Create(request.Object, descriptor.Object, controllerType)).Returns(Service);
   //+======================================================================+


   dispatcher.As<IDisposable>().Setup(disposable => disposable.Dispose());
   return dispatcher.Object;

}
```

My initial inclination was to think that the TimeController is not being returned by the mock because of `Create`s signature and the fact that my execution against the route is not providing the request and descriptor that match the mocks that were provided in the Activators Setup.

So, I swapped the creation of the Dispatcher with:
(request and controllerDescriptor replaced with `IsAny` checks)
       dispatcher.Setup(context => context.Create(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), controllerType)).Returns(Service);

but my requests don't hit the defined route.

Anyone know how to get my mock TimeController to come back in the call to `client.GetAsync`?

Comment: Whoops! I included the `dispatcher.Setup` code from an old attempt...so that probably doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  The reason for this question was that in my dispatcher.Setup(context => context.Create...) code, `request.Object` is actually `Moq.It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>` and `descriptor.Object` is actually `Moq.It.IsAny<HttpControllerDescriptor>` and I am still not able to get the request to hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq wasn't the problem. Inside my `Startup`, I had erroneously hidden the configured Attribute Routes behind an `IAppBulder.Map('NewRoute',...)`.¹  After fixing that nonsense, the code that I included above works as desired.  For completeness' sake, in case someone stumbles across this in research, I had to change my client code to get the test to pass:

```
using(WebApp.Start(url: "http://localhost:9000/", startup: startup.Configuration))
using(var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient))
{
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   using(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(ResourceUnderTest.ToString()).Result)
   {
      if(response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK){Assert.Fail("you suck");}

      String content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      DateTime actual = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(token);
      Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
   }
}

► Passed Tests (1)
   ✔ FluxCapacitor
```

..it's the same as the original code, except with ("application/json") set as the Accept header for the client.

```
¹ ...I guess that my [start-stop],[start-stop],[start-stop] cycle to 
deal with drive-by interruptions finally got to me yesterday. Since I 
(obviously) didn't know exactly what the culprit was, I was concerned enough 
that the problem was in my Mock that I wanted to raise the question to the 
community before I left for the day. But walked away and looked at it again 
with a new day's eyes and it took about 30 seconds to find the culprit.
```